# Camera2Video sample application - crash

Tags: android, sample-data

I try to start sample Camera2Video. I create new virtual device and use emulated camera with green or red foursquare. Application show preview wirking, but when i press start button - it`s crash with error:

> E/BufferQueueProducer: [GraphicBufferSource] queueBuffer: BufferQueue
>   has been abandoned
>       E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
>       E/BufferQueueProducer: [GraphicBufferSource] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
>       E/EGL_emulation: tid 4026: swapBuffers(322): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
>       E/CameraDeviceGLThread-0: Received exception on GL render thread:                                                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: swapBuffers: EGL error: 0x3003
>   at
>   android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.checkEglError(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:530)
>   at
>   android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.swapBuffers(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:523)
>   at
>   android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.drawIntoSurfaces(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:727)
>   at
>   android.hardware.camera2.legacy.GLThreadManager$1.handleMessage(GLThreadManager.java:105)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>       I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state ERROR
>       E/RequestThread-0: Timed out while waiting for request to complete.
>       W/CaptureCollector: Preview buffers dropped for request: 0
>       E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot receive result while in state: 0
>       E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot receive result while in state: 0
>       E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot receive result while in state: 0
>       E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab751140

This is class of sample application:
CameraActivity:

```
package com.example.android.camera2video;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        if (null == savedInstanceState) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, Camera2VideoFragment.newInstance())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

AutoFitTextureView:

```
package com.example.android.camera2video;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.TextureView;
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {
    private int mRatioWidth = 0;
    private int mRatioHeight = 0;

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
        }
        mRatioWidth = width;
        mRatioHeight = height;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
                setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
            } else {
                setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Camera2VideoFragment:

```
package com.example.android.camera2video;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Camera2VideoFragment extends Fragment
        implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    private static final String TAG = "Camera2VideoFragment";
    private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";

    private static final String[] VIDEO_PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
    };

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;

    private Button mButtonVideo;

    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;

    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession;

     private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
            = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                              int width, int height) {
            openCamera(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                                int width, int height) {
            configureTransform(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        }

    };

    private Size mPreviewSize;

    private Size mVideoSize;

    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;

    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    private boolean mIsRecordingVideo;

    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;

    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;

    private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);

    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            startPreview();
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            if (null != mTextureView) {
                configureTransform(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null != activity) {
                activity.finish();
            }
        }

    };

    public static Camera2VideoFragment newInstance() {
        return new Camera2VideoFragment();
    }

    private static Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
        for (Size size : choices) {
            if (size.getWidth() == size.getHeight() * 4 / 3 && size.getWidth() <= 1080) {
                return size;
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable video size");
        return choices[choices.length - 1];
    }


    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
        // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
        int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
        int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
        for (Size option : choices) {
            if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w &&
                    option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }

        // Pick the smallest of those, assuming we found any
        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
            return choices[0];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera2_video, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
        mButtonVideo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.video);
        mButtonVideo.setOnClickListener(this);
        view.findViewById(R.id.info).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.video: {
                if (mIsRecordingVideo) {
                    stopRecordingVideo();
                } else {
                    startRecordingVideo();
                }
                break;
            }
            case R.id.info: {
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (null != activity) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                            .setMessage(R.string.intro_message)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    /**
     * Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets whether you should show UI with rationale for requesting permissions.
     *
     * @param permissions The permissions your app wants to request.
     * @return Whether you can show permission rationale UI.
     */
    private boolean shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(String[] permissions) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (FragmentCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Requests permissions needed for recording video.
     */
    private void requestVideoPermissions() {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(VIDEO_PERMISSIONS)) {
            new ConfirmationDialog().show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        } else {
            FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(this, VIDEO_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (grantResults.length == VIDEO_PERMISSIONS.length) {
                for (int result : grantResults) {
                    if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.permission_request))
                                .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.permission_request))
                        .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPermissionsGranted(String[] permissions) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tries to open a {@link CameraDevice}. The result is listened by `mStateCallback`.
     */
    private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
        if (!hasPermissionsGranted(VIDEO_PERMISSIONS)) {
            requestVideoPermissions();
            return;
        }
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == activity || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "tryAcquire");
            if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
            }
            String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];

            // Choose the sizes for camera preview and video recording
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics
                    .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                    width, height, mVideoSize);

            int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            } else {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            }
            configureTransform(width, height);
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, mStateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Cannot access the camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            activity.finish();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
            // device this code runs.
            ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.camera_error))
                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.");
        }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        try {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
            if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            if (null != mMediaRecorder) {
                mMediaRecorder.release();
                mMediaRecorder = null;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.");
        } finally {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        }
    }


    private void startPreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            setUpMediaRecorder();
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>();

            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            surfaces.add(previewSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
            surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

      private void updatePreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(mPreviewBuilder);
            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
            thread.start();
            mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(CaptureRequest.Builder builder) {
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    }

    private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max(
                    (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                    (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        }
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }

    private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getVideoFile(activity).getAbsolutePath());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }

    private File getVideoFile(Context context) {
        return new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "video.mp4");
    }

    private void startRecordingVideo() {
        try {
            // UI
            mButtonVideo.setText(R.string.stop);
            mIsRecordingVideo = true;

            // Start recording
            mMediaRecorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecordingVideo() {
        // UI
        mIsRecordingVideo = false;
        mButtonVideo.setText(R.string.record);
        // Stop recording
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (null != activity) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Video saved: " + getVideoFile(activity),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        startPreview();
    }

    static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }

    }

    public static class ErrorDialog extends DialogFragment {

        private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

        public static ErrorDialog newInstance(String message) {
            ErrorDialog dialog = new ErrorDialog();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
            dialog.setArguments(args);
            return dialog;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Activity activity = getActivity();
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                    .setMessage(getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE))
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            activity.finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();
        }

    }

    public static class ConfirmationDialog extends DialogFragment {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Fragment parent = getParentFragment();
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setMessage(R.string.permission_request)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(parent, VIDEO_PERMISSIONS,
                                    REQUEST_VIDEO_PERMISSIONS);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    parent.getActivity().finish();
                                }
                            })
                    .create();
        }

    }

}
```

I`m beginner in android, please help - Why is this error? 
And how I can fix this error?

Camera2Video sample available on git repository and write - that all works.

Thank you.